# Mapping the pinout of an illuminated switch to a circuit

Tags: switches, wiring

I'm trying to figure out how to make the [following momentary switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/A22NZ-BNM-TWA/Z6671-ND/5603700) behave as follows:

- The switch is normally open
- When pushed down, it closes; when you release it, it goes back to being open (I assume there's a spring inside of it?)
- When closed, it sends an output signal out of 1+ of its pins, and it also illuminates the LED inside of it

According to the wiring:

[image: wiring]

It looks like I want to connect this switch to a circuit using Pins 3 and 4 (for being open at rest) as well as hooking pins X1 and X2 up to a circuit to turn the LED on when closed.

I'm wondering what this wiring would actually look like. Say we start with the switch at rest (so, open). Now I push the switch down, closing it:

[image]

What is happening to all 4 pins (3, 4, X1 and X2) when I close the switch and what do I wire these pins to? For instance:

1. When closed, does either X1 or X2 need to be connected to ground (`GND`)? Let's say I wire X2 to GND, what does the other one wire to, 6VDC power (`VCC`)?
2. When closed, what specifically is happening to *both* Pins 3 and 4? Does Pin 4 need to be connected to the 6VDC power, and Pin 3 will emit a signal when the circuit is closed? Or is it vice versa, or something else entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: exact P/N? >...............?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 (+1) sorry not following your question...

Comment: As I read the description and datasheets for   
A22NZ-BNM-TWA, that is the push-button actuator only, without any switch contact blocks or lamp sockets.  You would have to order Normally-Open or Normally-Closed switch blocks and a lamp socket separately.

Comment: My question was what is your exact P/n?   
A22NZ-BNM-TWA  ??

Comment: Ahh, didn'tknow what "p/n" was, according to that link, the Manufacturer Part Number is *A22NZ-BNM-TWA*.

Comment: @PeterBennett, jeez, I was under the impression they were all included...any idea where I could find the Normally-Open switch blocks & lamp socket that go with this particular push button/actuator?

Comment: I suggest you contact Digikey and confirm your  P/N meets your  requirements for 5V on LED   A22NZ-BNM-TWA

Comment: Smeeb   your diagram does nothing to power the light which needs 6Vac across it or 6Vdc,, but for convenience 5Vdc will work but half brightness. If you wanted the LED normally Lit use the unused NC switch for the LED then OFF when pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHHcfB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>